# How to choose Java version for Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I downloaded Android Studio latest version and installed Java 8. When I launch Android Studio I got below image.

[image]

Android studio found my Java version is 1.6 which is deprecate to run it. But I have installed java 1.8.0_101 and set the JAVA_HOME correctly. Please see below terminal output:

```
zhaoyi0113:Contents zhaoyi0113$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home
zhaoyi0113:Contents zhaoyi0113$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)
```

I wonder how to setup java version for android studio?

**EDIT1**

I have tried to reboot my mac os but it still got the same error.

**EDIT2**

This dialog block me using android studio so there is no chance for me to click android studio menu or doing any configuration on it. When I click the update button, my browser will be open to jdk1.6 download page.

Comment: You might want to logout / reboot to clear your old environment variables

Comment: I have tried to reboot my mac os but still got the same error.

Comment: What happens when you click the Update button?

Comment: What version is inside your *Info.plist* file ?

Comment: I found this documentation. Dunno if it'll help.  http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration/osx-jdk

Comment: @cricket_007 When I click update button, my browser will be open to jdk 1.6 download page.

Comment: Strange... All I can really suggest is using Homebrew + Cask to download both Java and Android Studio again. Seems to work on my Mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must edit Info.plist : 
to right click on the icon for the Android application Studio and choose " Show Package Contents "

Open Contents/Info.plist with a TextEdit, at the line :

```
<key>JVMVersion</key>
  <string>1.6</string>
```

, changes in

```
<key>JVMVersion</key>
  <string>1.7*,1.8+</string>
```

Sorry for my very bad english !

Answer (score 0):

Go to `File > Project Structure` and pick the correct SDK and JDK location.

Comment: I couldn't open android studio so there is no chance for me to click file menu